# Horizontal scrollbar not working as expected in react for table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am going to implement horizontal scroll for table and vertical scroll for tbody. Like this https://codepen.io/bashid92/pen/LgoQRK but I am confusing to convert jQuery code to react js. working ex expected in jQuery but how can we add into react or if anyone know how add that codepen scroll logic to tanstack react table please add. please help. Thanks in advance.

jQuery code: https://codepen.io/bashid92/pen/LgoQRK react(need to add that jQuery functionality):  https://codesandbox.io/s/table-scrolling-ybuj84?file=/src/App.js

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
     
        $("#"+this.id+" > *").width($(this).width() + $(this).scrollLeft());
    });
```

```css
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table.table-condensed.table-striped {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
.table-condensed.table-striped thead, .table-condensed.table-striped tbody {
    display: block;
}
.table-condensed.table-striped tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 420px;
}
.table>thead>tr>th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.table-condensed.table-striped td, .table-condensed.table-striped th {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 150px;
} 
.tablehead {
    background-color: #5e5e60;
    color: #fff;
}
.table-condensed>thead.tablehead>tr>th {
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.table-condensed>tbody.tablebody>tr>td {
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #4d4d4f;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #e4e4e5;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tablewrapper">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" id="table1">
                    <thead class="tablehead">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="">City</th>
                            <th class="">No of Guest</th>
                            <th class="">Occupancy</th>
                            <th class="">Aloce</th>
                            <th class="">APR</th>
                            <th class="">Nationality</th>
                            <th class="">Title</th>
                            <th class="">City</th>
                            <th class="">No of Guest</th>
                            <th class="">Occupancy</th>
                            <th class="">Aloce</th>
                            <th class="">APR</th>
                            <th class="">Nationality</th>
                            <th class="">Title</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="tablebody">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                            <td>Abu Dhabi</td>
                            <td>36789</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>2.45</td>
                            <td>700 AED</td>
                            <td>India</td>
                            <td>Occupied Rooms</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's much better to post your code in this question instead of just links. Otherwise, your links may break eventually and then this question will become useless for the community. Can you please copy / paste only relevant code into your question?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher added code. help me to write that jQuery code with react standards